# Google Maps API Javascript - Creating markers from select list

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a select option as follows...

```
<select multiple id="waypoints" th:field="${deliveries}">
        <option th:each="delivery: ${deliveries}" th:value="${delivery.addresses.street1}" th:text="${delivery.addresses.street1}"></option>
    </select>
```

and i am creating the markers like this

```
var locations = document.getElementById('waypoints');
        var x;


        for (x = 0; x < locations.length; x++) {
            var location = locations.options[x].text
            window.alert(location)
            //LOCATION IS CORRECT
            $.getJSON(
                    'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
                            + location + '&sensor=false', null, function(
                            data) {

                        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

                        var contentString = location
                        //LOCATION IS ALWAYS THE LAST ONE IN LIST?
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content : contentString
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position : latlng,
                            animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            map : map,
                        });
                        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                        gmarkers.push(marker);
                    });
        }
```

The markers are created properly, however they all the same content, which is the last item of the list. I have commented the code for more insight. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That is because your variable isn't scoped correct. When your callback gets called your loop has finished and `location` will be the last in the list.

One way to accomplish this would be to replace the `for`-loop with a `Array.forEach`.

Comment: Was still having problems with Array.forEach. It did not want to cycle through the select options. Found another solution provided below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue with

```
$("#waypoints > option").each(function() {

});
```

instead of using the for loop.

FULL CODE

```
 $("#waypoints > option").each(function() {
            var location = this.text
            $.getJSON(
                    'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
                            + location + '&sensor=false', null, function(
                            data) {

                        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

                        var contentString = location
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content : contentString
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position : latlng,
                            animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            map : map,
                        });
                        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                        gmarkers.push(marker);
                    });
```